# How to make upload work in asp mvc 2?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I have used the code provided in this link for the upload-handling:

http://towardsnext.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/file-upload-in-aspnet-mvc/

But this isn't working for me. (when I click the "Upload file" button when I'm running the site nothing happens.)
I have edited my view like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({bgiframe: true, height: 140, modal: true, autoOpen: false, resizable: false}) });
</script>
```

and also

```
<div id="dialog" title="Upload files">
                    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = item.OrderId })){%>
                        <p><input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" size="23"/> </p>
                        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p>
                    <% } %>
                </div>
                <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false">Upload File</a>
```

My Upload-function (defined in UploadController) looks like this:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
using System.IO;
using SiteVCM.Models;

namespace SiteVCM.Controllers
{
    public class FileDescription
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string WebPath { get; set; }
        public long Size { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    }

```
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    StoreEntities storeDB = new StoreEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Upload/

    FileRepository fileRepository = new FileRepository();

    //public ActionResult Index()
    //{
    //    return View(fileRepository.GetAllFileDescription());
    //}

    public ActionResult Upload(int id)
    {
        foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[inputTagName];
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Samples")
                    , Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(filePath);

                var order = storeDB.Orders.Single(c => c.OrderId == id);
                order.Url = filePath;
                storeDB.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Status", new { id = 0 });
    }

}
```

and the FileRepository.cs file is the same except for the namespacing and the place to ut the files in.

The JQuery Dialog box pops up like it should but when I click on the "Upload File" button nothing happens.

The view this code is in belongs to antoher controller then the one my Upload-function is defined in.

Please help me I've been looking for hours to fix this and I freaking me out.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are there any javascript errors? (Have you checked via Firebug?)

Comment: *Not working* could mean many things like: getting an exception (in which case you provide the exception details), not behaving as expected (in which case you explain what is the expected and the actual result), your computer crashes with a blue screen of death, apples start falling from the sky, ...

Comment: @Pino: I don't know wether there are javascript errors or not.
@Darin: I expect to have a file in my map /.Samples/ and a link in Order.Url. But when I click the "Upload File"- button nothing happens. No fileupload and no link, not even another action. Just nothing. It is like  clicking on a button which has no action linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for sure

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, 
  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){%>
     <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
<% } %>

public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
{
  //fileUpload == posted file
}
```

Comment: Hi, I was able to call the upload function in the upload-controller, but it didn't save my file to the specified map

Comment: It appears the fileUpload had the value of null when I clicked on the submit button. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Myst3ric It can be null if enctype is unspecified and/or input name != "fileUpload" (same as action parameter name).

Comment: they are the same but the variable is still null.